# A programmatic method for disabling all sharing services?

Tags: applescript, sharing, script

I'm seeking a programmatic method for disabling all the sharing services on a Mac. My preference is for an AppleScript or a shell script.

I'd like to have the services shown in the picture below disabled when I execute the script. The solution should be compatible with Alfred, Keyboard Maestro or any other global productivity tool.

The services I'd like to disable are:

[image: Sharing options]

I could come up with the following with some googling:

### File sharing (on/off)

```
do shell script "/usr/sbin/AppleFileServer" password "x" with administrator privileges
do shell script "/usr/bin/killall AppleFileServer" password "x" with administrator privileges
```

### Internet Sharing (on/off)

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.InternetSharing.plist
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.InternetSharing.plist
```

(*I would prefer terminal commands or batch scripts to apple scripts*. Here's an [apple script solution](http://www.macworld.com/article/157370/2011/01/applescriptsystempreferences.html) for those interested.)

Comment: Would you accept an app that does this sort of change automatically based on your location settings? [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com) and [an alt link](http://lifehacker.com/5855882/controlplane-automatically-changes-settings-on-your-mac-based-on-criteria-you-specify) because his site seems to be down today...

Comment: Thanks Ian, but would prefer to have this done purely with built in commands.

Comment: To be clear, you want these services off with minimal side effects, right? For instance `sudo shutdown -h now` will disable the services, but it will have other effects as well.

Comment: @Daniel : yup that is correct. I basically want the programmatic/terminal command equivalent of going to System Preferences and unchecking the sharing options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a shell script that turns off the services, but I'm working on finding a more direct solution:

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript << HERE
tell application "System Preferences" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    click menu item "Sharing" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
    delay 2
    tell window "Sharing" to repeat with x from 1 to 11
        if value of checkbox 1 of row x of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 is 1 then click checkbox 1 of row x of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1
    end repeat
end tell
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
HERE
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. This is helpful, but will definitely wait for your direct solution. That would be ideal! Cheers.

Comment: I recognize that it would be ideal, and I hope I can come up with it :-) -- but I can't promise I'll be successful.

Comment: Glad you're trying. You look like someone who can come up with the solution :) . Marking your answer cause it's the best available solution at the moment and you should get the cred on this. Do try the direct solution as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget you can simply execute your AppleScript at the command-line using the `osascript` tool rather than embedding it `<<EOF` style within the script as Daniel [suggests](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9388/daniel).

That means you can reuse the script you know already works with a one line shell script:

```
osascript ChangeSettings.scpt
```

(assuming `ChangeSettings.scpt` is the file in the current working directory containing the AppleScript you mentioned)

Comment: Intriguing - using a shell script to call the apple script. And since the OP is asking for user level scripting, this should work just fine for to reuse the Apple Script. It may not be the OP's choice unless they were unaware of the ability to reuse the chosen AppleScript but launch from the shell.

Comment: But be aware that the specific script linked in the question doesn't exactly do what the OP requested

Comment: @Kit Thanks. didn't know about osascript. good stuff. 

My main reason for requesting a "direct" terminal/bash command over an Apple Script is purely for performance purposes. Running a command over terminal like the ones posted in my question is definitely faster than the equivalent UI AppleScripting. 

So your point is well taken, but I would prefer to have the shell perform the direct command, rather than acting as a shell for an AppleScript call. Cheers.