# automating "Reset Advertising Identifier" is it possible?

Tags: macos, script, automation, privacy

I want to use osascript or some other way to automate "Reset Advertising Identifier" is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

#### Example #1 - via Googling

Googling I found this Reddit thread titled: [I want to write auto reset script for Advertising Identifier](https://www.reddit.com/r/applescript/comments/9sv1ol/i_want_to_write_auto_reset_script_for_advertising/).

The script from one of the replies in that thread is below.

**NOTE:** I did not test this, am merely sharing it as something that may help steer you in the right direction to ultimately getting a workable solution for you problem.

> FYI, I created a small script for this. It's not perfect, and doesn't
>   reliably run in the background, but in case it helps anyone:
>
> ```
> -- TODO: make this run reliably in the background...
> set isRunning to false
> if application "System Preferences" is running then set isRunning to true
>
> tell application "System Preferences"
>   activate
>   reveal anchor "Privacy" of pane "com.apple.preference.security"
> end tell
>
> tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
>   delay 0.3
>   click button "Reset Advertising Identifier" of group 1 of tab group 1 of window "Security & Privacy"
>   delay 0.2
>   click button "Reset identifier" of sheet 1 of window "Security & Privacy"
> end tell
>
> if isRunning is false then
>   quit application "System Preferences"
> end if
> ```

Script appears to be AppleScript.

#### Example #2 - I made using Automator

This is the first script I've ever done using Automator (be kind). I used the record button and clicked through the steps to construct a Workflow.

*Automator Workflow*

[image: ssautomatorwf1]

Once I made he workflow I copy/pasted it into ScriptEditor.

*Automator with steps*

[image: ssautomatorwf2]

*Copy/Paste from Automator → ScriptEditor*

[image: ssscripteditorcopypaste]

In ScriptEditor I could click the play button to run the script to debug it and see that it was working correctly.

*ScriptEditor Play Button*

[image: ssscripteditorplaybtn]

One I had it working reasonably well, I put it into a Bash shell script so that I could run it standalone from a terminal.

And here's the finished Bash script with the `osascript` embedded within:

```
$ cat reset_advertisement_id.sh
#!/bin/bash

osascript <<HERE
-- Click the “Apple” menu.
delay 4.598414
set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
set uiScript to "click menu bar item \"Apple\" of menu bar 1 of application process \"Finder\""
my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)

-- System Preferences…
delay 1.185682
set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
set uiScript to "click menu item 4 of menu 1 of menu bar item \"Apple\" of menu bar 1 of application process \"Finder\""
my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)

-- Click the “View” menu.
delay 4.124994
set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
set uiScript to "click menu bar item \"View\" of menu bar 1 of application process \"System Preferences\""
my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)

-- Security & Privacy
delay 2.306638
set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
set uiScript to "click menu item \"Security & Privacy\" of menu 1 of menu bar item \"View\" of menu bar 1 of application process \"System Preferences\""
my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)

-- Click the “Privacy” tab.
delay 4.31466
set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
set uiScript to "click radio button \"Privacy\" of tab group 1 of window \"Security & Privacy\" of application process \"System Preferences\""
my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)

-- Click the text “Advertising”
delay 1.997132
set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
set uiScript to "click static text 1 of UI Element 1 of row 12 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window \"Security & Privacy\" of application process \"System Preferences\""
my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)

-- Click the “Reset Advertising Identifier” button.
delay 1.234389
set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
set uiScript to "click UI Element \"Reset Advertising Identifier\" of group 1 of tab group 1 of window \"Security & Privacy\" of application process \"System Preferences\""
my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)

-- Click the “Reset identifier” button.
delay 1.2831
set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
set uiScript to "click UI Element \"Reset identifier\" of sheet 1 of window \"Security & Privacy\" of application process \"System Preferences\""
my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)

-- Click the “<fill in title>” button.
delay 1.436771
set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
set uiScript to "click UI Element 6 of window \"Security & Privacy\" of application process \"System Preferences\""
my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)

on doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
    set endDate to (current date) + timeoutSeconds
    repeat
        try
            run script "tell application \"System Events\"
" & uiScript & "
end tell"
            exit repeat
        on error errorMessage
            if ((current date) > endDate) then
                error "Can not " & uiScript
            end if
        end try
    end repeat
end doWithTimeout
HERE

# REFS
# - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html
# - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40944/a-programmatic-method-for-disabling-all-sharing-services
# - https://github.com/herrbischoff/awesome-macos-command-line
# - https://www.macobserver.com/tips/quick-tip/reset-mac-advertising-identifier/
# - https://scriptingosx.com/2018/08/user-interaction-from-bash-scripts/
# - https://www.macworld.com/article/1157370/applescriptsystempreferences.html
```

To run this:

```
$ ./reset_advertisement_id.sh
```

#### References

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript_Editor
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript

Comment: Not sure whether you tested the code to see if the code would work, but the script as coded will absolutely fail under default conditions. Meaning that unless one has previously gone to System Preferences  > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Advertising and not since clicked elsewhere within the System Preferences > Security & Privacy path, that is the only possible way as coded it might work. I say might, because with UI scripting the value of the `delay` command can be a break point and other methods should be use too. There is critical code missing from the script!

Comment: @user3439894 - no I didn't try it out, I'm not familiar w/ AppleScripts. I'm a long term Linux/UNIX person who is digging more into macOS. I tried to characterize this as something I found. Let me add a note stating that it's untested by me so that it's clear to anyone that this is an untested approach that may get you started but may need to be tweaked.

Comment: @user3439894 - I added a disclaimer.

Comment: JSYK... A critical piece of code that's missing is `select row 12 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window "Security & Privacy" of application process "System Preferences"` and would go before the `click button "Reset Advertising Identifier" ...` line of code. However, that line at this point in time is only good on macOS Mojave in a default install and may be subject to change on the `row` number and as such should be coded differently, but with the other poor coding practices in the script, it goes well with it. :)

Comment: @user3439894 - I took a wag at making my own `osascript` using Automator, lmk how that looks pls.

Comment: Since you asked, I wouldn't do it that way. Here is an example of how I'd code it: https://paste.ee/p/uvyek

Comment: @user3439894 - ah nice, the repeats make a much slicker way to do the `try...until` things occur. Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: @user3439894 - so is Automator in this capacity basically trash then? The code it emits isn't all that robust with the static times it emits. Also how can you find out the elements of the UI in macOS? In Linux you can use a CLI to actively investigate tehe X elements on the desktop to find out their scoped naming.